# A group of CSS buttons aligned

Tags: css

I have a group of buttons generated dynamically, so I need to align them as according follow example:

[image]

The 1st, 2nd and 3rd buttons must be expanded to fill full line width and keep with the same size.
The 4th and 5th buttons must be 50% each one to divide the same line in full.

I'm using the follow code but have no idea how to format as desired.

```css
.block {
  width: 400px;
}

.button {
  float: left;
  background-color: #cec;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="button"><a href="#">#1 - A LONG TEXT GOES HERE</a>
  </div>
  <div class="button"><a href="#">#2 - ANOTHER LONG TEXT HERE</a>
  </div>
  <div class="button"><a href="#">#3 - SOME TEXT HERE</a>
  </div>
  <div class="button"><a href="#">#4 - SHORT TEXT</a>
  </div>
  <div class="button"><a href="#">#5 - SHORT</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your HTML is working as described in the question, can you elaborate more, and describe exactly what issue is?

Comment: I want to let all buttons aligned... the large ones must fill the full line, the short ones since they are less than 50% of width they must be at the same line, but aligned with large ones at left and right. Sorry if I can't explain better, I don't speak english so well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of what it seems like you are asking for. Flex works well for making sure the longer text examples are the full size of the block. Unfortunately, it doesn't work well for getting the smaller ones to be exactly equal width, as the remaining space is portioned out between them after their normal widths.

```css
.block {
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.button {
  background-color: #cec;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="button"><a href="#">#1 - A LONG TEXT GOES HERE</a>
  </div>
  <div class="button"><a href="#">#2 - ANOTHER LONG TEXT HERE</a>
  </div>
  <div class="button"><a href="#">#3 - SOME TEXT HERE</a>
  </div>
  <div class="button"><a href="#">#4 - SHORT TEXT</a>
  </div>
  <div class="button"><a href="#">#5 - SHORT</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a fiddle since stacksnippets is down at the time of posting: https://jsfiddle.net/6vamdcz2/

Answer (score 1):

This is to add-on what @Zachary Haber has solved. If we want button 4 and 5 to have equal width, we can add another flex setup for button 4 and 5.

```css
.block {
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.button {
  background-color: #cec;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 15px;  
  font-size: 16px;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.button.button45 {
  flex: 1;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="button"><a href="#">#1 - A LONG TEXT GOES HERE</a>
  </div>
  <div class="button"><a href="#">#2 - ANOTHER LONG TEXT HERE</a>
  </div>
  <div class="button"><a href="#">#3 - SOME TEXT HERE</a>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="button button45"><a href="#">#4 - SHORT TEXT</a>
    </div>
    <div class="button button45"><a href="#">#5 - SHORT</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good solution but in my case I have buttons generated dynamically, so there is impossible to style buttons 4 or 5 because we don't know which one will be larger or shorter. Thank you anyway for your help.

Comment: Didn't know that. Anyway, not really helping.